# How to check Blob objects for equality?

Tags: apex, blob

Rather disappointingly for [Blob](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_blob.htm)s this assertion fails:

```
System.assert(Blob.valueOf('abc') == Blob.valueOf('abc'));
```

though the Apex [Expression Operators](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_understanding.htm) documentation over ambitiously says that:

> Unlike Java, == in Apex compares object value equality, not reference
>   equality, except for user-defined types.

So it seems that to test equality where the blobs have the same size requires the blobs to be put through [EncodingUtil.base64Encode](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm) which may lead to heap limit problems e.g.:

```
private static Boolean eq(Blob b1, Blob b2) {
    if (b1.size() == b2.size()) {
        String s1 = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(b1);
        String s2 = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(b2);
        return s1 == s2;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I there a better way to go?

Comment: I just tried your code... it didn't fail. Perhaps you could provide a legitimately broken example instead of the apparent oversimplification here?

Comment: @sfdcfox Duh... Not sure what I did wrong the first time. Please add that as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equals operator `==` does work as expected with Blob, so there's no reason to jump through extra hoops, such as your `eq` method. However, one possibility is that you may have had a different case in your code; since Blobs are binary data, they are case-sensitive in respect to equality:

```
Blob a = blob.valueof('hello world'),
    b = blob.valueof('Hello world');
system.assertequals(a, b); // Assertion fails
```

This is in contrast to normal String comparison, which is case-insensitive.

Comment: The problem was API version; the class with the comparison was set to version 29.0 and changing it to 43.0 fixed it. Thought I already had made that change but when double checking I had not.